# How i can display all posts order by years

Tags: loop

I want to display all the posts separated by years. Like that.

**2017**

- Post 1 / december 17
- Post 2 / July 7
- Post 3 / March 25

**2016**

- Post 1 /  december 25
- Post 2 / July 14
- Post 3 / March 31

The code I actually have is totally different of what i want, because after try a lot of posibilities doesnt work. BTW I type here how actually I have. A loop with a tittle, excerpt, date, tags, author and a link to read more. I only want to mantain the name of the post, the date, and a link to read more. This posts separate by years as I explain before.

```
<!-- language: lang-php --> 

<?php if( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
  <article class="">
  <div class"">
  <h2 class=""><a class="" href="<?php the_permalink();  ?>"><?php the_title();  ?></a></h2>
  <p>
  <span class=""> <small class=""></span> <?php comments_number( 'sin comentarios', 'un comentario', '% comentarios' ); ?></small>
  <span class=""> </span><small class=""> <?php the_date(); ?> </small>
      </p>
      </div>
      <?php the_post_thumbnail("medium") ?>
      <div class=""><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
      <div class="">
        <br>
        <small>Por: <?php the_author(); ?> </small>
        <small><?php the_author_meta("description"); ?></small>
      </div>
      <a class="" href="<?php the_permalink() ;?>">Seguir Leyendo</a>
    </article>
    <div class=""></div>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<p><?php get_the_posts_pagination() ?></p>
<P class=""><?php echo paginate_links( $args ); ?></P>
```

Comment: Hey Juan,  show us what you've tried so we can help you troubleshoot.  Code etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an if statement current loop to print out a year container around your articles.

```
<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php $current_year = date('Y'); // Get the current year and set it

    $first = true; // Set a $first variable;

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        if ( $first || get_the_date('Y') != $current_year ) :

            if ( !$first ) :

                // Not first, so close previous year container 
                echo '</div><!-- .year-' . $current_year . ' -->';

            else :

                // Is first, so set $first to false
                $first = false;

            endif;

            // Set the new $current_year
            $current_year = get_the_date('Y');

            // Print out new year container
            echo '<div class="year year-' . $current_year . '">' .
                     '<div class="year-header">' . $current_year . '</div>';

        endif; ?>

        <article>
            {{ Article Content Goes Here }}
        </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php // Close the last year container created by our while loop.
    echo '</div><!-- .year-' . $current_year . ' -->'; ?>

<?php else : ?>

<?php endif; ?>
{{ Pagination Goes Here }}
```

Just remember to replace the notes in the code with your actual article & pagination with your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article:

http://alex.leonard.ie/2010/07/27/wordpress-tip-get-the-date-of-your-first-post/

Use the function to get the first or last post year, and add it to your posts page as a string.

192.168.0.16/wordpress.example/blog/*functionDateFirstPost()*/?order=dec